# Ionic FCM push notifications observable does not emit

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am doing the following in an ionic application:

1. When a user is logged in, subscribe to their user ID topic
2. When a push notification arrives, `console.log` something.

   ```
   this.authState.subscribe((state) => {
       if (state) {
           this.fcmPush.subscribeToTopic(state.uid);

           this.fcmPush.onNotification().subscribe(notification => {
               if (notification.wasTapped) {
                 console.log('Received in background', notification);
               } else {
                 console.log('Received in foreground', notification);
               }
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Source: https://github.com/AmitMY/ionic-starter-firebase/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts#L118

Sending a notification to my own topic arrives (after a few minutes), but I never see anything in console, both from outside the app, and inside the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sending a notification from firebase messaging does not work.
However, using the sdk I must add:

`click_action: "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",`

Which is in the usage guide but I missed